# GPLライセンスのソフトウェアを利用したサービスのソースコードの公開義務

Tags: ライセンス, gpl

例えば、WordPressのようなGPLライセンスが適用されているソフトウェアの一部をカスタマイズし、そのカスタマイズ版を用いてWEBサービスの提供を行っています。

この場合、アプリケーションの配布を行っているわけではないので利用者へのソースコードの配布は不要であると認識しております。

一方で、例えば、このサービスを第三者に譲渡する場合は譲渡先がソースコードの開示を要求した場合、かならず提供しなければならないという認識です
（もっとも、PHPですのでバイナリというのはレアですが）

このような認識でいるのですが私の認識はあっていますか？

Answer (score 12, accepted):

GPLの "ASP loophole(抜け穴)" 問題として認識されていることもあり、質問にある解釈が一般的かと思います。このようなGPL解釈に対して、別ライセンス [Affero General Public License(AGPL)](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affero_General_Public_License) が準備されています。

下記記事も参考になります。

- [さよならコピーレフト](http://www.itmedia.co.jp/enterprise/articles/0606/13/news013.html)
- [GPLとサービスとしてのソフトウェア](http://www.yamdas.org/column/technique/the_gpl_and_sof_1j.html) （原題"The GPL and Software as a Service"）

Comment: 参考リンクありがとうございます。非常に参考になりました。ありがとうございました。